# Apple's TestFlight and Push Notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I'm working on an app and testing it with my partners via Apple's New TestFlight. I've never had issues with the old TestFlight system but now all of a sudden if I install the app via USB Cable & Xcode notifications come streaming in.

However if I install via Apple's TestFlight notifications never get delivered.

I'm using Parse for notifications and again have never had any problems. Anyone else have any issues or advice? Pretty frustrating.

Comment: Hi there - I have the same problem. I tried most combination of certificates but for none I get the push messages delivered. The funny thing is that if I compile local and use developer certificates and provisioning profiles the pushs are delivered. I tried to use an AdHoc provisioning profile with distribution cert but its not working over testflight - any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Ok. Well it would seem that Apple's New TestFlight considers any version pushed "production". Therefore you must have a production certificate generated as well. Best best is to use an AdHoc Provisioning Profile which will use the production push certificate. Don't use a Development Provisioning Profile with a Development Push Certificate.

The more you know...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem...where did you find that info?

Comment: When you upload an app to Apple's test flight you do it the same way as for the Store itself. You are compiling the App in release so it will use the production credentials. Because of this you will need to send the push notifications using the production certificate.